# Put MySQL result into different strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT img_name FROM images WHERE prod_id = 5
```

Now the result outputs 3 images from the database which is as expected.

```
IMG_NAME
------------
afront_img.jpg 
back_img.jpg   
side_img.jpg
```

How do I put the different images into say:

```
$image1 = result 1 from db
$image2 = result 2 from db
$image3 = result 3 from db
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Moslem Ben Dhaou. Your marking my question down due to my poor formatting doesn't look nice. I'm just new in here and learning to adapt. If this is your way of making one stay here by this form of discouraging then you make no good help after all.

Comment: Just for the notice, I reviewed your question I did not vote it down. Somebody may have did for his reasons: ASK HIM

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I am sorry it wasn't you. I learnt already a better way to format from you. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would query and get the result object using mysql connecting using PHP

Following code should help you
Refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
For understanding more on fetching array

```
<?php
/**
Considering your have made connection using mysqli
$con = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","db1");
*/

$query = "SELECT img_name FROM images WHERE prod_id = 5";
$result = $con -> exec_query($query);
$imageArr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);){
    $imageArr[] = $row['img_name'];
}
var_dump($imageArr); // Displays your Image array
?>
```

Comment: $imageArr = array(); Just solves the whole puzzle because once the result is passed into an array then all can be accessed using different array keys.

Comment: @rsakhale Thanks man. This solved it all for me. Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! You've made my day. I am able to call them as I like where I needed them. I keep learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Would like some more info, but let's just assume assume the column "img_name" contains several imagelinks seperated by a special char, for example a |.

Then you can do:

```
$images = explode('|', $result_sql);
$image1 = $images[0];
$image2 = $images[1];
$image3 = $images[2];
```

**Edit**

Or this

```
$images = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $sql_result);
$image1 = $images[0];
$image2 = $images[1];
$image3 = $images[2];
```

Comment: They have no separators. I can't post images as i don't have up to 10 points yet. I edited my question so I post sample result from database.

Comment: Your SQL result output seem to have a linebreak after each imagelink, is that correct? If so, see my updated answer. That preg_split should split the string ($sql_result) by \r\n, whitespace, comma etc.